# flex - reinvoking Operation after faultevent

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, remoteobject

After invoking a RemoteObject, we sometimes need to reinvoke the same operation until it succeeds.

```
private var myserviceRO:RemoteObject = new RemoteObject("myService");
[...]
myserviceRO.operationName.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, myResultHandler);
myserviceRO.operationName.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT, myFaultHandler);
myserviceRO.operationName(arg1, arg2, arg3);
[...]

 protected function myFaultHandler(faultEvent:FaultEvent):void {
        //under some condition, resend the operation that failed
        (faultEvent.currentTarget as Operation).send();

        //under some condition, resend the operation that failed
        (faultEvent.currentTarget as Operation).send((faultEvent.currentTarget as Operation).arguments);
 }
```

Now as my operation requires 3 arguments, and i have no idea how to pass the parameters to the *send()* method:

- when i call send(), i get an error : "0 argument passed, 3 expected"
- when i call send(operation.arguments), i get "1 argument passed, 3 expected"

The send() documentation specifies that :

> - Executes the method. Any arguments passed in are passed along as part of
> - the method call. If there are no arguments passed, the arguments object
> - is used as the source of parameters.

So if i don't send any arguments, the original arguments are supposed to be used, but apparently the aren't.

Debugging my application shows that  **(faultEvent.currentTarget as Operation).argumentNames** is allways an **empty array**, and **arguments** is allways an **empty Object**.

Can you please tell me how to pass the parameters ?

thank you.

Comment: This would create an endless loop if the service call never succeeded, wouldn't it?

Comment: yeah but we do have some conditions on the error (only for Network errors) and a maximum number of attempts.

Comment: The AsyncToken may have stored what you need http://flexdiary.blogspot.com/2010/02/debugging-responder-result-functions.html (or you could add it if not)

Comment: @AmyBlankenship i don't know how to access the AsyncToken from myFaultHandler() ?
Thank you again

Comment: @AmyBlankenship i figured it out: faultEvent.token.message.body
Thank you :)
I'm gonna answer the question

Comment: On a site note: i'd rather use the explicit cast Operation(faultEvent.currentTarget).arguements ... or even better create a local variable because the error pop right in your eye. With 'as', you just get an 1009 TyperError. But that just on a site note.

Comment: @FlorianSalihovic thank you for the hint, but i allways check the type before i do the cast :
if ( faultEvent.currentTarget *is* Operation) (faultEvent.currentTarget as Operation).send()

Comment: Then a better style would be: const o:Operation = event.currentTarget as Operation; if (o) o.send() else trace('null'); <- the way you only cast once, which is a quite expensive operation. Well, just some comment - best regards.

Comment: @FlorianSalihovic thank you for the hint about the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution:

```
protected function myFaultHandler(faultEvent:FaultEvent):void {
    //Parameters should be set beforehand from the async token
    ((Operation)faultEvent.currentTarget).arguments = faultEvent.token.message.body;

    //Now the parameters are ok
    ((Operation)faultEvent.currentTarget).send();


 }
```

Credits to @AmyBlankenship blog:
http://flexdiary.blogspot.com/2010/02/debugging-responder-result-functions.html